# noUiSlider linking error

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

I get the following error when trying to use the [libLink feature with NoUISlider](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/examples/):

**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (jquery.liblink.js:260**

The line of code:

```
// If the Link requires creation of a new element,
    // Pass the element and request confirmation to get the changehandler.
    // Set the method to be called when a Link changes.
    linkInstance.changeHandlerMethod = this.LinkConfirm( flag, linkInstance.el );
```

In my HTML I have the following code:

```
<div id="slider" ></div>
```

My Javascript:

```
$("#slider").noUiSlider({
    start: 20,
    range: {
        'min': 10,
        'max': 50
    }
});

$("#slider").Link('lower').to('-inline-');
```

I have both the NoUISlider and liblink libraries included in the page.

I don't get to see the value label. How can I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: `<div id="slider" ></div>` - without `#`

Comment: @panther it's without the #, I wrote it manually, my mistake.

Comment: Are you running this code on document.ready?

Comment: Code runs fine: http://jsfiddle.net/xnchoL65/ What is the difference to your actual setup?

Answer (score 5):

Was happening with me too.

Get the newest js files and it works fine.